# C++, Is it safe to static_cast to void* and back across processes?

Tags: c++, ipc, type-safety, static-cast, memory-safety

I have two identical binaries running at the same time on a Linux system (different command line arguments, so they are doing different things). In one process, I memcopy an object into some shared memory region; and in another process, I retrieve the object with the correct size, and get a  pointer to it as a `void*`, and `static_cast` it to a pointer of the original type.

Is this considered safe? The object is not necessarily POD.

Comment: you should never use `void*`

Comment: @JakeFreeman This is an exaggeration, when dealing with raw memory void* is pretty common. `malloc`, `memcpy`, etc.

Comment: In practice, yes, and Folly implements this as long as the class has no pointers to internal data members, references, or is virtual. In pure theory, no. Folly, Bloimberg, and the EASTL all have their own version of type relocation, to avoid move constructors, which basically all involve memcpy at some level for nontrivial types.

Comment: @NirFriedman in general for C++ you never need to directly use `void*`

Comment: If you are doing a memcopy on a struct that has only C members, you should be okay.  If you are doing memcopy on a struct that has C++ objects, you'll be in a world of hurt.

Comment: @JakeFreeman I don't know what this means "in general". If you just use standard containers and allocators and never do anything low level, then no, you don't "need" to. But many of us using C++ are sometimes working with raw memory in various contexts and write code that calls those functions or other C API directly. And in that case, we do need to. I do agree it's almost always possible to avoid, and most cases where I need to use it I'd be sure to wrap it in the narrowest context possible.

Comment: Using `void*` is often unavoidable due to low-level (OS) API's. However, in C++ you would wrap those interfaces in a typesafe C++ interface. This localized the use of `void*` to a single place (generally a class), so the bulk of your application is not affected.

Answer (score 2):

It's not safe, because you can't memcpy an object that isn't trivially_copyable. For example you can't move/copy `std::vector` by calling memcopy on it, that can lead to lots of issues. You can however construct the object into the shared memory segment. I highly recommend looking at boost interprocess; even if you don't use it the examples will give you a sense of what's possible: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html.

Comment: To be fair, the chance your computer will blow up for memcpying data for most non-trivial is pretty low, unless that type is virtual, contains a reference, or a pointer to an internal variable. Major libraries like Folly use it extensively. https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/FBVector.md#object-relocation

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: `memcpy`-ing a `std::vector<T>` to shared memory is bound to blow up in the other process, even when it contains no pointers to _internal_ variables. The problem is that your `memcpy` will copy the vector object itself, which is typically just a bunch of `T*` pointing to heap-allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

The *language* says nothing about shared memory, so in that sense the question is unanswerable.  In practice, the restriction to trivially-copyable is the right idea; since it is permitted to give such objects values via `memcpy`, the compiler will not usually make any unfortunate optimizations.

You do have to watch out for the memory being loaded at different addresses in different processes.  If the object *contains* no pointers, this can be ignored.  If it does, you might want [`offset_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html).